# RFID tag Toggle LED switch

Tags: c, arduino, switch-statement, nfc, rfid

I have this example code (MFRC522 - DumpInfo -  https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) - working fine, in the serial monitor I can see "Card UID".

I'm trying it for 2days (just a beginner) but have no idea, how to "extract" Card UID so I can make an if statement to turn ON LED when the correct UID RFID tag is presented. 
+ when presented again, LED will turn OFF. (Toggle switch with RFID).

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10         // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);     // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    while (!Serial);        // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
    SPI.begin();            // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();     // Init MFRC522
    delay(4);               // Optional delay. Some board do need more time after init to be ready, see Readme
    mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();  // Show details of PCD - MFRC522 Card Reader details
    Serial.println(F("Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks..."));
}

void loop() {
    // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;
    }

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;
    }

    // Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called
    mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
}
```

Will appreciate your help, happy coding :)

Comment: You're quite far away from where you're going. Have you looked at the access control [example](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/examples/AccessControl/AccessControl.ino)?

Comment: that's actually pretty amazing, almost the same I was looking for. Just added two if statements & it's ready now :) Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. It might be a good idea to a answer on your own question if you have the time.